# Using Testflight does not receive crashes

Tags: objective-c, ios, crash-reports, testflight

I've installed Testflight (1.2 B3) as stated in the documentation. Builds are uploading and updating fine. I can see sessions (mostly anonymous :/), I receive the logs (TFLog) - but I do not receive any crash reports. I even introduced a crash-on-event (a method not found thing) - but theres is nothing on Testflight about it.

Provisioning is via a developer profile which embeds several devices.
The problem occurs on iOS6 and iOS5 / iPhone5 and iPad3. The is being build against iOS6.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
I've tested several other frameworks and ways to receive crash reports. Nothing worked so I suspect something in my code (obviously). Are there any other switches that XCode 4.5.1 might have enabled and that way disable any error reporting during a "production environment" like setup?

**UPDATE 2**
As of now we're using Testflight only for distribution of beta versions and switched to Crashlytics for crash reporting. It's a bit more streamlined and fetches most crashes.

Comment: do you mean the testflight website / session log, or the caches directory? The testflight website states correct starting and ending of sessions - as if the handler has not been set or something. I had a different handler in my project but rest assured I removed all of it.

Comment: when you are clicking on a build and then crashes it displays a - but there are several crashes in my case.

Comment: Nope. Nothing. The crash fields for the build display '0'

Comment: for sure. I explicitly invoked a method call that does not exist.

Comment: I've also seeing this. I deliberately write data to an invalid address  when I push a button, and the app crashes. But the 'Crashes' column in 'Manage your builds' does not indicate any crash. The same problem, I guess?

Comment: The problem is still not fixed.  Same situation.

Comment: Any updates on this? I believe I'm experiencing the same problem (although I'm using MonoTouch so there is another layer of indirection, I do still believe it is the same issue).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testflight did not satisfy our needs to log crashes. That is why we skipped to Crashlytics (as I said in the original post). The issues with Testflight seem not to be resolved. We still do use it for distribution, that is what it's good at.

Comment: I found when I didn't include the `***.app.dSYM` in the upload to testflight then I wouldn't get Crash reports did you include this when uploading?

Comment: @Popeye how do you include the dSYM when uploading app to Testflight ?

Answer (score 5):

I also do not get any crash reports via TestFlight. This is what the TestFlight people told me:

> Our team is currently looking into an issue associated with auto
>   versioning of the app when uploaded and SDK data not reporting
>   properly. Looking at the URL you provided it looks like the build
>   version is not changing before uploading the app to TestFlight and our
>   auto versioning implementation is causing an issue with general SDK
>   data reporting.
>
> I will share this with our team and we will contact you when we have
>   an update available.

I tried to update the build version to avoid auto-versioning, but it did not help me. But maybe this issue is hitting someone else.

Comment: Mhm. My version changes every time. At least my internal version. Would be great if you'd update this post when you got an answer.

Comment: I am not getting any crash reports either. I have my build number updating each time the compiler is run, but my version number is so far fixed at 0.001.  I have a "4" next to Sessions, but when I go into sessions, it shows 2 sessions for Anonymous User.  I'd also be keen to know if TestFlight gets back to you about the issue.

Comment: The first time my app crashed, it was reported correctly. Subsequent crashes don't show at all though. Sessions are showing up ok, however. It also seems to be having trouble using the .dSYM file I uploaded to symbolicate the crash - not sure whether it's supposed to be able to symbolicate crashes after they've occurred

Comment: I experienced the same behavior as @RichTolley

Comment: I have the same issue, it says 2 crashes but when go inte the crashes section, nothing is there.

Comment: If TestFlight receives crash reports on a version of an App that has not been uploaded to TestFlight, what does TestFlight do? Just drop the data?